# orderby multiple meta_keys and then orderby date_modified

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-order-by

A post is created for each talent with a status of either `coming-soon` or `in-town` or `others` saved as `meta_values`. I needed to display posts first by "coming-soon" and then "intown" and then "others".

I realized that I was looking for **orderby multiple meta_keys** and found a [solution here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/246355/order-by-multiple-meta-key-and-meta-value/#answer-246358). I converted the syntax in order for it to work with `pre_get_posts` hook ( since it is main loop in category.php). As I need, code below mostly works and shows results ordered by `coming-soon->in-town->others`.

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'pre_get_posts_hook' );
function pre_get_posts_hook($wp_query) {
      if (is_category() && $wp_query->is_main_query()) {

          $wp_query->set('meta_query', 
                      array( 'relation' => 'OR',                 
                             'soon' => array( 'key' => 'coming_soon',                                                            
                                              'value'   => 'yes',                                                                                 
                                              'compare' => '='
                                               ),
                              town' => array( 'key' => 'in-town',
                                              'value'   => 'positive',    
                                              'compare' => '='
                                              ),
                              'others' => array( 'key' => 'others',                                                                                           
                                              'value' => 'null',                                  
                                              'compare' => '='
                                              )                                         
                           )
                   );
        $wp_query->set('orderby', array('soon' => 'DESC', 'town' => 'DESC', 'others' => 'DESC'));
        return $wp_query;
    }
}
```

Now, I need to run a second level of orderby. I mean, with the code above, first I get the posts with meta_key `coming-soon`, I expect these posts to be **again** ordered by `date_modified` and possibly a control on their order eg. ASC, DESC. I am quite sure that it is possible. I just have no clue how do I nest it further.

Comment: @halfer it is called being polite, not begging, as you wrote in your revision-title. Norrow thinking bro, not cool. I agree that it was unnecessary, but so is your revision-title.

Comment: No offence intended gurung, just wading against the [tide of pleading](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22please%20help%20me%20out%22%20closed%3ano) on the site. "Please help me" is also code for "do it for me", so is worth avoiding just on that score. [This is worth a read too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**. I will leave the answer in case it may help someone in future. I had to replace this line.

```
$wp_query->set('orderby', array('soon' => 'DESC', 'town' => 'DESC', 'others' => 'DESC'));
```

with this line.

```
$wp_query->set('orderby', array('meta_value' => 'DESC', 'modified' => 'DESC' ));
```

I think the code is pretty self-explanatory. What it does is, it will allow you to run you primary-orderby and then once you get those results, you can run a secondar-orderby. Of course, the second associative array is not limited to `modified`, it can be any other [parameters of orderby](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters). Eg. title, author etc.